# Cypress Error after running open command...'error loading V8 startup snapshot file'. I'm not able to run cypress then

Tags: installation, cypress, snapshot, initializer

The exact error is:
[0328/091115.205:FATAL:v8_initializer.cc(447)] Error loading V8 startup snapshot file

Could you please help to fix and be able to use Cypress?

I tried (steps):

First: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/cypress-example>npm install
Second: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/cypress-example>npx cypress run

(both command using cmd.exe as administrator permission and I was running it in the file of the website example that I criated...C:/inetpub/wwwroot/cyrpress-teste)

exact error bellow:

Cypress failed to start.

This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

Please refer to the error below for more details.

---

[0328/091115.205:FATAL:v8_initializer.cc(447)] Error loading V8 startup snapshot file

---

Platform: win32-x64 (10.0.19044)
Cypress Version: 9.5.2

Comment: Maybe something happened during the install. Have you uninstall and reinstalled cypress?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in cypress v9.5.4

Solved this by installing older version.

Just uninstall the current version, write **"cypress": "^8.4.1"** and run `npm i`

Comment: So you're saying no one is using version after 8.4.1?

Comment: please, I sill get this error even after installing ^8.4.1, please do you have any other solution?